# Vscode Webpack Bable running react components from a different project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, visual-studio-code, babeljs

I have 2 react projects using babel and webpack each with the same folder called 'frontend'. Sometimes when I switch the projects in the vscode editor and try running the newly opened project, it displays the components that I had used in the previous project but no where to be found in the current one. Does anyone know how this could be? I was following a build setup for this set of videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQXhG1eZGLM&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kCLWnGmK0jUBmGLaJxvi4j&index=6